# Adrunio-LED control

Tags: python, arduino

I was trying to write a code to blink an LED 3 times which is connected to an Arduino from Python. I was able to do so, but even after the python code stops running, the LED keeps on blinking. Codes are attached, any suggestions?

Python code

```
import serial #import the pyserial library
connected = False #this will represent whether or not ardunio is connected to the system
ser = serial.Serial("COM3",9600) #open the serial port on which Ardunio is connected to, this will coommunicate to the serial port where ardunio is connected, the number which is there is called baud rate, this will provide the speed at which the communication happens
while not connected: #you have to loop until the ardunio gets ready, now when the ardunio gets ready, blink the led in the ardunio
    serin = ser.read()
    connected = True
    ser.write('1') #this will blink the led in the ardunio
    while ser.read() == '1': #now once the led blinks, the ardunio gets    message back from the serial port and it get freed from the loop!
ser.read()
ser.close()
```

Ardunio code

```
void setup() {
 Serial.begin(9600);
 pinMode(10,OUTPUT);
 Serial.write('1');
}
void loop() {
if(Serial.available()>0){
  digitalWrite(10,HIGH);
  delay(500);
  digitalWrite(10,LOW);
  delay(500);
  digitalWrite(10,HIGH);
  delay(500);
  digitalWrite(10,LOW);
  delay(500);
  digitalWrite(10,HIGH);
  delay(500);
  digitalWrite(10,LOW);
  Serial.write('0');
```

}
 }

Comment: Arduino shouldn't perform any Serial.write in your example. It should constantly perform Serial.read. if the value is 1 then turn on the LED and if 0 turn off.
Python should write 1 and 0 to turn on/off the led

Comment: @Ramast why is that? I don't see why a device shouldn't respond to commands. that's a stupid advice, then some day you end up like me, being forced to talk to a Chinese industrial equipment that just doesn't respond to anyhting. no errors, no confirmation, nothing. that's real fun...

Comment: @Piglet Because sending zeroes continuously isn't a _response_ and it's what keeps the code from working as intended.

Comment: That's not valid Python code.

Comment: @gre_gor what u mean by that?

Comment: @marcosidaho gre_gor probably is pointing out that your code example is not properly indented.

Comment: It's still improperly indented. Why do some people have such horrible problems with copy pasting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition with [`Serial.available()`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Available) is always true because there is always (the same old) data available. You need to read the data to remove it from the buffer.

Comment: Do u mean to flush the memory?

Comment: `flush()` is badly named and does not clear the input buffer with the current Arduino versions (see note in documentation). Try what Ramast suggests in the first comment to your question. Reading from Serial will take data from the input buffer. Once it's empty, `available()` will return 0 and the condition evaluates false: your blink code will not execute then.

Comment: @ flush I have modified the audrino code a bit, i changed from Serial.write('1') to Serial.read(). But now the process is not getting disconnected in python!